# Disable arrow-key function on Foundation 6 Tabs

Tags: tabs, zurb-foundation

Does anyone know how to disable the use of arrow-keys on Foundation 6 tabs? For example, if you click on a tab to make it active and scroll down, the second tab becomes active rather than actually scrolling down the page.

Answer (score 0):

This is meant for accessibility reasons and you can not easoly remove this by default.

The keys are registered through the keyboard class.

https://github.com/foundation/foundation-sites/blob/develop/js/foundation.tabs.js#L33

```
    Keyboard.register('Tabs', {
      'ENTER': 'open',
      'SPACE': 'open',
      'ARROW_RIGHT': 'next',
      'ARROW_UP': 'previous',
      'ARROW_DOWN': 'next',
      'ARROW_LEFT': 'previous'
      // 'TAB': 'next',
      // 'SHIFT_TAB': 'previous'
    });
```

https://github.com/foundation/foundation-sites/blob/develop/js/foundation.util.keyboard.js

https://github.com/foundation/foundation-sites/blob/develop/js/foundation.util.keyboard.js#L23

The keys are handled in https://github.com/foundation/foundation-sites/blob/develop/js/foundation.tabs.js#L221

You can probably catch the event, prevent bubbling and throw them away if it is one of the keys that you do not want to handle.